# Can someone tell me how to do operations with double?

Tags: java, double, precision

double x= 2.2,y=2.13;

How can i do do operations like  x+y or x-y * x/y?
For example x-y should be 0.07 but java gives me 0.07000000000000028

Comment: You did the operation correctly. But there's limits on how precise a double can be saved internatlly. Use BigDecimal instead.

Comment: 0.07 can not be exactly represented by a floating point number.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");   System.out.print(df.format(x)); It will simply cut your result but it will not affect the calculation itself it will be still with the double precision.

Answer (score -4):

You can use Math.round() function.

```
import java.lang.Math;
System.out.println(Math.round(x-y));
```

Comment: Why do you think this helps in this case? What do you think `Math.round(0.07000000000000028)` returns?

Comment: As i understand that you need a simply precised result for a double precision. so Math.round will work and return you 0.07

Comment: You understand incorrectly.  The javadoc says: "Returns the closest long to the argument, with ties rounding to positive infinity.".  So the result will actually be an integer ... zero.

Comment: @AzamAbbasi why 0.07? Why not 0.0700000000000003? Why not 0.1?

Comment: I agree with @Stephen C